# Finding filename by its count in a directory using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a directory with thousands of files, and I need to find specific filenames by file count (files are sorted by name or date).

Is there an easy way to make it using cmd commands?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give an example. What you are asking is not so clear

Comment: ok. I have a directory. It has, let's say 2000 files. I need to get filename of a file which is 11th in the list, so i need something like this (use pseudo-code of mine) 'get filename[_count_]' ('get filename[11]' for example).

Comment: or something like  `directory.sort('date').getFilenameByCount(11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 11th file then you want to skip the first 10. Here is a simple batch file that does the trick. Change the DIR command in the FOR IN() clause to get the results you need.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d') do set "chosenFile=%%F" & goto break
:break
echo The 11th file is %chosenFile%
exit /b
```

If all you want to do is list the 11th file to the screen, then you can do this on the command line:

```
cmd /c "for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d') do echo %F&exit"
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly is it listed on the screen?

Comment: I open cmd, type "E:" then type `for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d') do echo %F`  and I get the entire list of files printed

Comment: @momijigari - You didn't type in what I have in my answer. My command executes EXIT after printing out the 11th file. The entire command is enclosed in quotes and exeuctued via another CMD.EXE shell, so the EXIT does not close your command window. You can copy the entire line from the answer and then paste into your command window. To paste you can right click on the command window title area and select Edit followed by Paste.